# How to write this simple javascript code in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want this code in javascript:

```
beforeNode = children[  children.length -1 ]
```

With this fragment of code in coffeecript:

```
beforeNode = children[  children.length -1 ]
```

coffescript generate:

```
beforeNode = children[children.length(-1)];
```

How can I write source in coffescript to generate expected javascript code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a space!

```
// coffeescript
beforeNode = children[children.length-1]
```

Or use a space on each side of the `-`

```
// coffeescript
beforeNode = children[children.length - 1]
```

Results in

```
// js
var beforeNode;

beforeNode = children[children.length - 1];
```

Comment: I would prefer instead to use a space between `-` and `1`... i.e., `beforeNode = children[children.length - 1]`.

Comment: @GauthamBadhrinathan updated answer to show this is possible too

Answer (score 0):

Or use two spaces!

```
# coffeescript
beforeNode = children[children.length - 1]
```

Results in

```
// javascript
var beforeNode;

beforeNode = children[children.length - 1];
```